# Kotlin Gradle Project using readln Causes Memory Error

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I am a new Kotlin programmer who has experience in Java; though, not with Gradle.

I created my project `Shell/` using the [Gradle Build Tool](https://gradle.org/install/).

I ran the command `gradle init --type kotlin-application` and created a new Kotlin Gradle project.

So, after creating the project via the Gradle Build Tool in my Terminal, I opened it up inside of Intellij.

Gradle had a boilerplate Hello World which I executed using `./gradlew build` and then `./gradlew run` inside of my Terminal; these commands worked fine, and I saw a "Hello World" output.

Then I changed the code up, and added this:

```
val PROMPT = ">>> "

while (true) {
    print(PROMPT)
    val userInput = readln()

    println(userInput)
}
```

When I execute this code inside of Intellij, it works; however, when I run it inside of the Terminal with the same commands used earlier, I get:

Output for `./gradlew build`

```
Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 668ms
7 actionable tasks: 7 up-to-date
```

Output for `./gradlew run`

```
Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain
a java executable      

> Task :app:run FAILED
>>> Exception in thread "main" kotlin.io.ReadAfterEOFException: EOF has already been reached
        at kotlin.io.ConsoleKt.readln(Console.kt:152)
        at pure.sass.AppKt.main(App.kt:9)
        at pure.sass.AppKt.main(App.kt)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

My JAVA_HOME is set to `usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`

My directory `usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11` only has a `src.zip` file in it

Comment: EOF has nothing to do with the memory. I assume it simply says the stdin has been closed. I'm a little surprised because I would assume `gradle run` allows to start a command line tool and pass stdin/stdout to/from it, but maybe I'm wrong. Maybe it is even executed by the Gradle Daemon and in that case it makes sense we can't pass an input to it.

Comment: If you want to execute it from the command line, you can run `./gradlew distZip`, then find the zip file somewhere in `build`, unpack it and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with Gradle.

I use a Kotlin DSL, and I added this in my `build.gradle.kts`:

```
tasks.named<JavaExec>("run") {
    standardInput = System.`in`
}
```

Comment: Yep, this fixes it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are dealing misconfiguration. Link to JAVA_HOME is wrong for a terminal or similar.

Did you tried to use java [toolchains](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html)? So you delegate to Gradle itself to set up dependency to Java JRE or JDK.

[Example](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html#sec:consuming):

```
java {
  toolchain {
    languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(11))
  }
}
```

While if you referring to following error: `EOF has already been reached`, you can't pass in arguments to Gradle when its executing the build. There are other ways how you [pass arguments to gradle build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html).

- Command-line flags
- System properties
- Gradle properties such as org.gradle.caching=true that are typically stored in a gradle.properties file in a project directory or in the GRADLE_USER_HOME.
- Environment variables